# Regex to match a string which doesn't start with

Tags: regex, velocity

We need a regex to identify Apache velocity syntax like comments and #foreach

Ex:

```
##Commenline #foreach
     #foreach($var in $vars)

    #end
```

Here we want a regex which matches #foreach in second line, but not in first line. How can I construct a RegEx for the same.

Comment: Do not use regex for this. Regex is horrible at nested things such as nested conditions and loops.

Comment: Anchor to start of string and allow only whitespace before `#foreach` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like:

```
(?m)^[ \t]*#(\w+)
```

Would match the second `#foreach` and `#end`.

It matches beginning of line followed by any number of spaces, a `#` and a number of word characters (`#` not included, so comments would not match).

`(?m)` is used to set multi-line mode. If your regex flavor does not support that use a corresponding flag in your regex API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\s*#.*$
```

This will grab the whole line of your targets. If you want just the first word, try this:

```
^\s*#\w+
```